# Make sendmail email me on SYSERR errors

Tags: email, sendmail

I'm running CentOS5 and sendmail and occasionally I get a line like this:

```
Oct  3 15:19:50 mail sendmail[23643]: s936Is4d023643: SYSERR(root): collect: I/O error on connection from web.address.com, from=<address@address.com>
```

I only get word of these errors after someone complains that an email didn't go out to a customer. I supposed I could write a Python script that checks /var/log/messages every few minutes and email me if it finds SYSERR, but is there a way to do this through sendmail?